# Combining Computer Science and Humanities

Tags: graphs, computer-vision, data-mining, history, computational-linguistics

I currently hold a bachelors in Computer science and a masters in Art History. I really want to combine the two and I know of Digital Humanities but I'm not completely aware of where Digital Humanists could work besides Museums, libraries, etc. and even at museums and the such, I imagine that the demand for Digital humanists isn't THAT large either. Does anyone have any idea of how I could combine art history and computer science and what kind of places could I work in? If I do go into digital humanities, do you think I'd be expected to work in cultural settings or could I still get a job at a purely science industry? Any response will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think this is on-topic here. If you're looking for career advice, [workplace.se] or [academia.se] would be more suitable.

Comment: @Discretelizard, I agree that it's not on topic here, but nor is it on topic in either of those sites. In fact, it's been closed as off-topic on Academia.

Comment: Oh? Why was it off-topic on Academia? Would 'carreer options based on current study' be off-topic on [workplace.se]?

Comment: It is unfortunate that you lack the reputation required to join [chat] or Academia's chat, as we could certainly help you there.